# Jitsi not logging to asterisk from ubuntu with SIP

Tags: sip, asterisk

I'm trying to use the jitsi client to connect with SIP to an asterisk server.

If I give my account name, I get a password error; if I give my extension, I get a time out.

I can log in with the extension from a windows jitsi client with the same parameters.

All software has been installed in the last few days with the last versions (jitsi 2.4.4997 and 2.5.5065 on Ubuntu, jitsi 2.4.4997 on windows), Asterisk 11.12 compiled from source).

I tried with and without firewall results are the same. Both Ubuntu and windoz computers are on the same network.

Could it be a problem with an external library?

Comment: how did you install the `jitsi` client?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it by specifying `nat=yes` in asterisk.